# Make angular using CanActive only some path at childRoutes

Tags: angular

i'm new with Angular

In my case, i want to use guard in some path

Shell.ts

```
export class Shell {
   static childRoutes(routes: Routes): Route {
       return {
           path: '',
           component: ShellComponent, // Component that have a navbar
           children: routes,
           canActivateChild: [AuthenticationGuard],
       };
   }
}
```

shell.component.html

```
// some code html of navbar here
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
   Shell.childRoutes([
      { path: 'module1', loadChildren: () => import('./module1/module1.module').then(m => m.module1) },
      { path: 'module2', loadChildren: () => import('./module2/module2.module').then(m => m.module2) },
      { path: 'module3', loadChildren: () => import('./module3/module3.module').then(m => m.module3) },
   ]),
];
```

I only want using canActivateChild for `module3`. How can I do it?

Comment: check my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need modify your `AuthenticationGuard` from `CanActivateChild` to `CanActivate`

Second, remove `canActivateChild: [AuthenticationGuard]` from `Shell.ts`

Third, if you need using authentication on `module1`, you just need add `canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]` to `app-routing.module.ts` like this:

```
{ path: 'module1', loadChildren: () => 
  import('./module1/module1.module').then(m => m.module1), canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
```

Answer (score 1):

in can activate check like  :-

```
allowedModules = ['module2','module3']

   filteredModule = allowedModules.find((module)=>state.url.includes(module));

   return !!filteredModule;
```

Comment: So when I have many modules that need canActiveChild then I will need more "if condition" and so will not be optimal. Do you have any solutions for that situation?